# Apache Configuration 404 Error

Tags: linux, apache, fedora

I'm running Apache on Fedora Workstation 24. I have a user "foo", with a directory "public_html", and an index.html file within that directory.

I want to be able to make a request to `localhost/~foo` and be served the html file. Currently I'm getting a 404 not found.

Commands used for install/config, and related files:

```
dnf install httpd
chmod 711 ~foo
chmod 755 ~foo/public_html
systemctl start httpd
```

From `/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf`:

```
#
# UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
# directory if a ~user request is received.
#
# The path to the end user account 'public_html' directory must be
# accessible to the webserver userid.  This usually means that ~userid
# must have permissions of 711, ~userid/public_html must have permissions
# of 755, and documents contained therein must be world-readable.
# Otherwise, the client will only receive a "403 Forbidden" message. 
#
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    #
    # UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
    # of a username on the system (depending on home directory
    # permissions).
    #
    # UserDir disabled

    #
    # To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
    # directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
    # the following line instead:
    #
    UserDir public_html
</IfModule>

#
# Control access to UserDir directories.  The following is an example
# for a site where these directories are restricted to read-only.
#
<Directory "/home/*/public_html">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>
```

The index file: /home/foo/public_html/index.html is world readable.

Any ideas why this is resulting in a 404? I can access `localhost/`. Since I'm not getting a 403, I'm assuming that this is not a permission error.

Comment: wich group got your root folder "public_html" apaches or www-data or user:user ? ls -la /home/user/ i guess find the rights user and all of them need to be in the group or apaches or www-data : sudo chown user:user /home/user/public_html... and if no running add them to the apache group. adduser user www-data ...

Comment: currently the user and group owner of the `public_html` directory is `foo`. `ls -ld /home/foo/public_html` outputs `drwxr-xr-x. 2 foo foo 4096 Oct 14 02:21 /home/foo/public_html`

Comment: And foo is in the user group of every user adding by a adduser or foo is  in the group www-data or apache???

Comment: foo is only a member of `foo`. I tried adding it to `apache`, but that doesn't help. Which groups should it be a member of?

Comment: look at the right group getting in this path /var/www try to add this foo user in this same group.